# Why do we care about a cow loan?

Tags: nedarim-shevuot, borrowing, tractate-nedarim

The *mishna*, *[N'darim](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Nedarim.4.6)* 4:6, in my own, very loose translation:

> Aaron asks Baruch, "Lend me your cow."
>
> Baruch tells him, "It's not available."
>
> Aaron says, "My field is forbidden to me like a sacrificial offering for plowing it with your cow."
>
> If it's his practice to plow, himself, then he cannot plow his field [with Baruch's cow, since that was what he meant when he forbade it], but others can. But if it's not his practice to plow, then [he meant that even others can't use Baruch's cow, so] neither he nor anyone else can [plow it with Baruch's cow].

Most of the other cases until this point in *N'darim* are not so detailed with respect to the background of the case. I'd expect something more like:

> Aaron says, "My field is forbidden to me like a sacrificial offering for plowing it with your cow."
>
> If it's his practice to plow, himself, then he cannot plow his field [with Baruch's cow, since that was what he meant when he forbade it], but others can. But if it's not his practice to plow, then [he meant that even others can't use Baruch's cow, so] neither he nor anyone else can [plow it with Baruch's cow].

— i.e., missing the initial conversation about the attempted loan. For example, earlier in [4:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Nedarim.4.6) is a case of someone who forbade himself his fellow's benefit (like here), but it doesn't say why. And the same is true in [4:5](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Nedarim.4.5), [4:4](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Nedarim.4.4), and numerous times in the preceding chapters. Why here does the *mishna* record a conversation of background information as to why Aaron forswore Baruch's benefit?

Answer (score 1):

The first line of [Nedarim 4:6](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Nedarim.4?lang=bi) states:

> המודר הנאה מחבירו לא ישאילנו
>   Reuven who takes a vow to forbid benefit from Shimon shouldn't lend [items] to him

The [**Tiferet Yisrael**'s explains](https://www.sefaria.org/Mishnah_Nedarim.4.6?lang=bi&p2=Yachin_on_Mishnah_Nedarim.4.50.1&lang2=bi&w2=all&lang3=en) this to mean:

> **גזירה** שמא ישאל ממנו
>   **this is a decree** to prevent Reuven from borrowing from Shimon

It seems the scenario subsequently detailed in the mishnah is a continuation of this first line and serves as an example as to why this *gezairah* was enacted.

Comment: I don't see how it serves as an example of why the _g'zera_ was enacted

Comment: @msh210 it would seem to be playing out the scenario of what led to enacting the *gezeira*

Comment: Tyt. אמר לו השאילני פרתך. לאו במודר ומדיר עסקינ